# About thermionic emission

Tags: electricity

Does thermionic emission have any limits? If we continued heating the metal plate can it reach a charge of 1 C ? Will the work function increase as the charge of the metal plate increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thermionic emission is just that emission, the removal of charge carriers from a material due to excess thermal energy. Therefore it is not possible to build up charge, although if you do not have a replenishing supply it is possible to deplete electrons.

On the other hand, it is possible to achieve extremely high current densities. A limit that I have heard is the melting temperature of the emitter, but it might come before that.

As an example consider tungsten, it can easily thermionically emit at temperatures of $2000\, \mathrm{K}$ (since its melting temperature is $3695\, \mathrm{K}$) and has a work function of $4.55\, \mathrm{eV}$, plugging this into the classic Richardson-Dushmann Equation

$J_{RD} = A_0 T^2 \exp(-\frac{\phi}{k_B T}) = 16.457747\, \frac{\mathrm{A}}{\mathrm{m^2}}$